# PHP Exits code from =>

Tags: php

I have a chunk of PHP given to me to put into a web page... the code looks like this:

```
<?php
$SVQuerystring = "";
foreach (($_GET) as $SVGetKey => $SVGetValue) {
....
?>
```

Problem is, everything after the '>' in the 3rd line gets printed as html text, so the php is being exited there. I can't find a similar issue anywhere, and I have never worked with PHP before. Any suggestions on what is wrong, or where to look? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is the page saved as a `.php` file, and is the server running PHP? What you've described is exactly what happens if you just paste the code snippet you gave into a plain HTML document: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/xNsRK/

Comment: It's not `=>` but it's `>` matching the `<` from `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously question whether the PHP is getting executed in the first place.

Try this code to make sure it is executing without any of your code.

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

If you see a bunch of output pertaining to PHP and your server then there is some other problem.  If you don't see any new output, then PHP is not correctly installed on your server.